# how to fix build gradle failure

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build

this is error code

```
Build file 'C:\Users\SSAFY\Desktop\jae\pjt1\sub1\skeleton-project\backend_skeleton\build.gradle' line: 19

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'ssafy'.
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.LazyPublishArtifact.<init>(Lorg/gradle/api/provider/Provider;)V

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 6s
```

this is my build.gradle file code

```
buildscript {
    ext {
//        springBootVersion = '2.4.9'
        springBootVersion = '2.3.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/release' }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'


    group = 'com.ssafy'
    version '0.0.1'

    targetCompatibility = 1.8
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

    configurations {
        developmentOnly
        runtimeClasspath {
            extendsFrom developmentOnly
        }
        compileOnly {
            extendsFrom annotationProcessor
        }
    }


    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

project(":core-module") {
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    bootJar.enabled = false
    jar.enabled = true

    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
        implementation('org.projectlombok:lombok')
        implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1'
        developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
        implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging')
        implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
        implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5'
        implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.3.1'
        // S3
        implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-aws', version: '2.2.1.RELEASE'

        runtime('com.h2database:h2')
        runtimeOnly 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client'
        testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")

        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

        //querydsl 추가
        implementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa'
        //querydsl 추가
        implementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt'
    }
}

project(":api-module") {
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    apply plugin: 'java-library'


    bootJar{
        archivesBaseName = 'ssafy'
        archiveFileName = 'ssafy-api-module-0.0.1.jar'
        archiveVersion = "0.0.1"
    }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core-module")
        implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
        implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1'
        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

        implementation 'net.rakugakibox.util:yaml-resource-bundle:1.1'
        implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-aws', version: '2.2.1.RELEASE'

        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.8.1'
        implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        implementation group: 'com.github.scribejava', name: 'scribejava-core', version: '8.3.1'
        implementation group: 'com.github.scribejava', name: 'scribejava-apis', version: '8.3.1'
        compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'
        compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.9.2'

        //JUnit4 추가
        testImplementation("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine") {
            exclude group: "org.hamcrest", module: "hamcrest-core"
        }

        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache')
        compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.11'
        compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.11'
        compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    }
}

project(":batch-module") {
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    apply plugin: 'java-library'


    bootJar{
        archivesBaseName = 'ssafy'
        archiveFileName = 'ssafy-batch-module-0.0.1.jar'
        archiveVersion = "0.0.1"
    }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core-module")
        implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

        implementation 'net.rakugakibox.util:yaml-resource-bundle:1.1'

        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.8.1'
        implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        implementation group: 'com.github.scribejava', name: 'scribejava-core', version: '8.3.1'
        implementation group: 'com.github.scribejava', name: 'scribejava-apis', version: '8.3.1'

        //JUnit4 추가
        testImplementation("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine") {
            exclude group: "org.hamcrest", module: "hamcrest-core"
        }

        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache')
        compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    }
}

project(":cms-module") {
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    apply plugin: 'java-library'


    bootJar{
        archivesBaseName = 'ssafy'
        archiveFileName = 'ssafy-cms-module-0.0.1.jar'
        archiveVersion = "0.0.1"
    }

    configurations {
        all {
            exclude group : 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core-module")
        implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
        implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5'
        implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1'
        implementation('nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect')
        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
        implementation group: 'org.thymeleaf.extras', name: 'thymeleaf-extras-java8time', version: '3.0.1.RELEASE'
        implementation 'org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:2.1.3'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'
        implementation 'org.bgee.log4jdbc-log4j2:log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4.1:1.16'
        implementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

        runtimeOnly 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client'
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test'
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'

        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'

        implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'

        annotationProcessor('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor')

    }
}
```

this is my project files
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilJrO.png)

this is line 19
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

i clone my homework git.

when i open this project by intellij
then start build
and error occurred

i did my java version downgrade to 1.8

how can i fix that?
please help me

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as [properly formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

From your questions, it seems you're encountering an issue when evaluating your root project with Gradle, specifically with the Spring Boot Gradle plugin. Here's the recommended structured approach to troubleshoot the issue:

1. Gradle Version Compatibility: Ensure that your Gradle version is compatible with the Spring Boot version you are using. Spring Boot 2.3.2.RELEASE should be compatible with Gradle 6.x versions. You can check your Gradle version with ./gradlew --version in the terminal.
2. Spring Boot Gradle Plugin: You've commented out a newer version of Spring Boot in your build.gradle file and are using an older one. It's possible there could be a compatibility issue with other dependencies or the Gradle version itself. Try uncommenting the newer version of Spring Boot, sync your project, and see if that resolves the issue.
3. Gradle Wrapper: Ensure you are using the Gradle wrapper rather than a globally installed version of Gradle. The wrapper ensures that everyone who works on the project uses the same Gradle version. You can execute Gradle wrapper commands using ./gradlew instead of gradle.
4. Java Version: Downgrading Java to version 1.8 is a good step, as Spring Boot 2.3.2.RELEASE is fully compatible with Java 8. Ensure that IntelliJ IDEA is configured to use JDK 1.8 by checking File -> Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Project and Project Settings -> Modules in IntelliJ IDEA.
5. Build Cache: Sometimes, the Gradle build cache can cause issues. Try cleaning the project with ./gradlew clean and then rebuild the project with ./gradlew build.
6. Gradle Scan: Running the build with the --scan option will provide insights and a detailed report of what happened during the build. This can be very useful for troubleshooting complex issues.
7. Plugin Declaration: Double-check the plugin declaration syntax. Since Gradle 5.x, the recommended way to apply plugins is using the plugins DSL. For example:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.2.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    // other plugins
}
```